what is Oracle view exu8con used for
I once found an Oracle system view SYS.EXU8CON, and its data seems to be relevant to information of all database objects, like object id, owner, etc. It also has some columns I can't tell what they are about, like CONDITION, CONDLENGTH, and SQLVER. And I even can`t find any information on Internet, which is so weird. So, anyone can explain that?
Having studied the data in the view and searched on the internet. Expecting to get table comments.

There's a suite of "exu..." prefixed views, which pertain to Oracle export operations. If you run
select view_name from dba_views
where view_name like 'EXU%';

you'll see there are plenty, typically for each style of thing you might want to export (tables, views, sequences, types etc etc)

There truly are.  And I would appreciate it if you could provide more details about these views. Just curious, though it seems they are of  no practical use.

They are for internal use (by our tools) which is why I wouldnt be using them in your own codebase, because we could add/change/drop them on a whim
